# Civi CRM on Joomla 5

Tags: joomla

any idea when civi crm compatible with Joomla 5.
Tried a test installation but it does not install on Joomla 5 and throw error during installation

Comment: Any idea if CIVI compatible for Joomla 5?

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM is "compatible" with Joomla 5. I run it on a Joomla 5.0.2-installation without problems.

Please make sure you have the Joomla compatibility plugin activated, as described here https://manual.joomla.org/migrations/44-50/compat-plugin/

What error did you get during the installation?